# form validation not performed, spring boot

Tags: spring, validation, spring-boot, spring-security

Perhaps I'm missing something little and stupid. However i have a form with 6 checkboxes, you can check at max 4 of those checkboxes at the same time and this is inside the validate method of the validator. My validator class is the following:

```
@Component
public class GraficiUserFormValidator implements Validator {

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> arg0) {
        return arg0.equals(GraficiUserForm.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object arg0, Errors arg1) {
        GraficiUserForm form = (GraficiUserForm) arg0;
        validateCheckBoxes(arg1, form);

    }

    private void validateCheckBoxes(Errors arg1, GraficiUserForm form) {
        if ((form.getG1().equals("on") && form.getG2().equals("on") && form.getG3().equals("on") && form.getG4().equals("on") &&
                form.getG5().equals("on") && form.getG6().equals("on")) ||(form.getG1().equals("on") && form.getG2().equals("on") && form.getG3().equals("on") && form.getG4().equals("on") &&
                form.getG5().equals("on"))||(form.getG1().equals("on") && form.getG2().equals("on") && form.getG3().equals("on") && form.getG4().equals("on") &&
                form.getG6().equals("on"))||(form.getG1().equals("on") && form.getG2().equals("on") && form.getG3().equals("on") && form.getG5().equals("on") &&
                form.getG6().equals("on"))||(form.getG1().equals("on") && form.getG2().equals("on") && form.getG4().equals("on") && form.getG5().equals("on") &&
                form.getG6().equals("on"))||(form.getG1().equals("on") && form.getG3().equals("on") && form.getG4().equals("on") && form.getG5().equals("on") &&
                form.getG6().equals("on"))||(form.getG2().equals("on") && form.getG3().equals("on") && form.getG4().equals("on") && form.getG5().equals("on") &&
                form.getG6().equals("on"))
                ){
            arg1.reject("grafici.tooMany", "Troppi grafici selezionati, si possono selezionare solo 4 grafici");
        }

    }

}
```

Then i autowired the validator to the Controller:

```
@Controller
public class UsersController {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UsersController.class);
    private final UserService userService;
    private final SitoService sitoService;
    private final ClusterService clusterService;
    private final GraficiUserFormValidator graficiUserFormValidator;

    @Autowired
    public UsersController(UserService userService, ClusterService clusterService, SitoService sitoService, GraficiUserFormValidator graficiUserFormValidator) {
        this.userService = userService;
        this.sitoService = sitoService;
        this.clusterService = clusterService;
        this.graficiUserFormValidator = graficiUserFormValidator;
    }

    @InitBinder("form")
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.addValidators(graficiUserFormValidator);
    }
```

and i built up the method for the form to be processed in the same controller:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ADMIN') or hasAuthority('CLUSTERADMIN') or hasAuthority('SITEADMIN')")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/update/settings", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String updateSettingsGraphs(@Valid GraficiUserForm form, HttpSession session, HttpServletRequest request, BindingResult result, 
            Model model, Long id){
        SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper wrapper = new SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper(request, null);

        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            if (wrapper.isUserInRole("ADMIN")) {
                result.reject("graphs.tooMany", "Puoi selezionare solo quattro grafici alla volta");
                Collection<User> users = userService.getAllUsers();
                model.addAttribute("users", users);


                for (User user : users) {
                    model.addAttribute("form"+user.getId().toString(), new GraficiUserForm());
                }

                return "users";
            }

            else if (wrapper.isUserInRole("CLUSTERADMIN")) {
                result.reject("graphs.tooMany", "Puoi selezionare solo quattro grafici alla volta");
                Collection<User> users = clusterService.getAllByCluster(id);
                model.addAttribute("users", users);


                for (User user : users) {
                    model.addAttribute("form"+user.getId().toString(), new GraficiUserForm());
                }
                return "users-cluster";
            }

            else {
                result.reject("graphs.tooMany", "Puoi selezionare solo quattro grafici alla volta");
                Collection<User> users = sitoService.getAllBySite(id);
                model.addAttribute("users", users);


                for (User user : users) {
                    model.addAttribute("form"+user.getId().toString(), new GraficiUserForm());
                }
                return "users-site";
            }
        }
        User user = userService.getUserById(form.getUserid());
        if("on".equals(form.getG1())){
            user.setG1("S");
        } else {
            user.setG1("N");
        }
        if("on".equals(form.getG2())){
            user.setG2("S");
        } else {
            user.setG2("N");
        }
        if("on".equals(form.getG3())){
            user.setG3("S");
        } else {
            user.setG3("N");
        }
        if("on".equals(form.getG4())){
            user.setG4("S");
        } else {
            user.setG4("N");
        }
        if("on".equals(form.getG5())){
            user.setG5("S");
        } else {
            user.setG5("N");
        }
        if("on".equals(form.getG6())){
            user.setG6("S");
        } else {
            user.setG6("N");
        }
        user = userService.save(user);
        if (wrapper.isUserInRole("ADMIN")) {
            return "redirect:/users";
        }

        else if (wrapper.isUserInRole("CLUSTERADMIN")) {
            return "redirect:/users-cluster";
        }

        else {
            return "redirect:/users-site";
        }

    }

}
```

My webpage is built by freemarker and is as follows:

```
<#-- @ftlvariable name="users" type="java.util.List<it.energyway.application.domain.User>" -->
<#-- @ftlvariable name="_csrf" type="org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfToken" -->
<#list users as user>
<#-- @ftlvariable name="form${user.id}" type="it.energyway.application.domain.GraficiUserForm" -->
</#list>
<#import "/spring.ftl" as spring>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="it">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>List of Users</title>
</head>
<body>

<nav role="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/">Dashboard</a></li>
        <li><a href="/user/create">Create a new user</a></li>
        <li>Amministrazione
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/users">Gestione  Utenti e Permessi</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<h1>Utenti</h1>

<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>E-mail</th>
        <th>Role</th>
        <th>Grafico 1</th>
        <th>Grafico 2</th>
        <th>Grafico 3</th>
        <th>Grafico 4</th>
        <th>Grafico 5</th>
        <th>Grafico 6</th>
        <th>Cambio</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <#list users as user>
    <form role="form${user.id}" name="form${user.id}" action="/update/settings" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="userid" id="userid" value="${user.id}"/>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="/user/${user.id}">${user.email}</a></td>
        <td>${user.role}</td>
        <td><input class="graphs" type="checkbox" name="g1" <#if (user.g1 == "S")>checked=true<#else></#if></td>
        <td><input class="graphs" type="checkbox" name="g2" <#if (user.g2 == "S")>checked=true<#else></#if></td>
        <td><input class="graphs" type="checkbox" name="g3" <#if (user.g3 == "S")>checked=true<#else></#if></td>
        <td><input class="graphs" type="checkbox" name="g4" <#if (user.g4 == "S")>checked=true<#else></#if></td>
        <td><input class="graphs" type="checkbox" name="g5" <#if (user.g5 == "S")>checked=true<#else></#if></td>
        <td><input class="graphs" type="checkbox" name="g6" <#if (user.g6 == "S")>checked=true<#else></#if></td>
        <td><button type="submit">Save</button></td>
    </tr>
    </form>
    </#list>
    </tbody>
</table>
<#list users as user>
    <@spring.bind "form${user.id}" />
</#list>
<#if (spring.status.error)??>
<ul>
    <#list spring.status.errorMessages as error>
        <li>${error}</li>
    </#list>
</ul><#else>
</#if>
</body>
</html>
```

When i select more than 4 checkboxes it doesn't throw any error in the output...
Anyone has any idea of why?

Comment: `BindingResult` must follow the argument annotated with `@Valid`. Yours is somewhere at the end instead of at the correct location. Also you don't need to wrap the request in the spring security one (that is already done for you by Spring Security).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try add this first in your controller method:

```java
ValidationUtils.invokeValidator(userFormValidator, form, result);
```

The `@Valid` annotation will trigger validation using JSR-303/JSR-349 (Bean Validation API) constraints and validators, but your validator specified above is a Spring validator.

**Update:** As *M. Deinum* has pointed out in comment, `@Valid` should work in conjunction with Spring validator(s) too, if `BindingResult` follows the argument with `@Valid` and you register the validator with `@InitBinder`. Well well, I have successfully used the method above when working with Spring validators, I guess I didn't find it logical to mix a JSR-303/349 annotation with Spring validator.

Comment: @M.Deinum I didn't know you could use it that way too! Made update.